# Trim and add to a 2d Array to Form a Rectangle

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array, `blocks`. This array has a lot of whitespace, and because it is user generated, I can't just fill it in manually. It might look something like this:

```
let blocks = [
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
  [0,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,0,0,0],
  [0,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,1,1,3,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,0,1,0,1,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
];
```

It does not have compleatly straight edges, and is not necessarily centered. I need to convert it into a compleatly recanglular grid, without any whitespace. Now, an easy way to do this would be to just take all the 0's, and convert those to a filler color, like 1. This would work, but would create very large maps for grids that could be much smaller. Because the edges are not straight, I will still have to use a filler, but I want to use the least possible amount of filler and create the smallest possible map for any grid.

In the case above, this would be the solution:

```
let blocks = [
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
  [1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
  [1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1],
  [1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,1,1,3],
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1],
];
```

How would I do this in js?

Here is the code, note that the end array is 1d, and that different things map to different numbers, bu the basics are still the same:

```
//Clip untill rectangle
        let minX = 0;
        let minY = 0;
        let maxX = 0;
        let maxY = 0;
        for(let y in this.map){
            for(let x in this.map[y]){
                if(this.map[y][x] != 'blank'){
                    maxY = Math.max(y, maxY);
                    minY = Math.min(y, minY);
                    maxX = Math.max(x, maxX);
                    minX = Math.min(x, minX);
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(minX, minY, maxX, maxY)
        //we now know the width and height
        let w = maxX - minX;
        let h = maxY - minY;


        //fill it up
        for(let y = minY; y < maxY; y++){
            for(let x = minX; x<= maxX; x++){
                let X = x - minX;
                let Y = y - minY;
                let place;//what we will place
                switch(this.map[y][x]){
                    case 'blank':
                        place = 1 + fillTheme;
                    break;
                    case 'open':
                        place = 0;
                    break;
                    case 'player up':
                        place = 5;
                    break;
                    case 'player left':
                        place = 6;
                    break;
                    case 'player down':
                        place = 7;
                    break;
                    case 'player right':
                        place = 8;
                    break;
                }
                map[Y*w+X] = place;
            }
        }
```

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: Here im editing the question to show my code right now

Comment: When I console log the width and height, those are both wrong, and there is undefinded spaces in the array

Comment: `minX` and `minY` need to be initialized to the width and height of the original array, not 0.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks @RaffleBuffle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traverse one time all rows and columns, mark the `rows` and `cols` to be deleted.
Now, with `filter` and `map` using above `rows` and `cols` easily get the required output.

```js
let blocks = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
];

const rows = blocks.map(() => true);
const cols = blocks[0].map(() => true);

for (let i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < blocks[0].length; j++) {
    rows[i] = rows[i] && blocks[i][j] === 0;
    cols[j] = cols[j] && blocks[i][j] === 0;
  }
}

const res = blocks
  .filter((_, i) => !rows[i])
  .map((arr) => arr.filter((_, j) => !cols[j]).map((x) => (x === 0 ? 1 : x)));

res.forEach((line) => console.log(JSON.stringify(line)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the array and filter the empty rows and collect column information, which are used to slice the filtered rows and then map falsy values with one.

```js
let blocks = [ [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
    cols = [],
    rows = blocks.filter(a => {
        let row = false;
        a.forEach((v, i) => {
            cols[i] = cols[i] || v;
            row = row || v;
        });
        return row;
    }),
    indices = cols.reduce((r, v, i) => {
        if (v) return [r[0], i + 1];
        if (r[0] === i) r[0]++;
        return r;
    }, [0, 0]),
    result = rows.map(a => a.slice(...indices).map(v => v || 1));
        
console.log(indices);
result.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```